# Zend Framework 1.1X.XX Installation

Tags: php, zend-framework, xampp

I want to work on the MVC structured Zend application.

I have **xampp V3.2 with PHP version 5.6** installed. 
I have downloaded the **Zend Framework 1.12.17** from the official download page. 
I am quite confused to set the **environmental variables** and **files to copy and paste** to the exact root folder structures in windows. 
Can anyone provide me the exact **step to step guide** so as to get the **ZF 1.12** running perfectly fine in windows.?
I have **windows 8.1 OS.**
It would be more appreciable if someone can provide me the guide here instead of pasting any link. Because, every other link tells various ways to install. And most of them are referring to ZF2.

Answer to this would be most appreciable. Thank you!

Comment: When I was new to Zend framework, this page(https://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/) had helped me a lot. I hope it will help you to.

Comment: I was using description from official site: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html Try something and ask specific question if you have problem with something.